# Problem using import/export in Javascript "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: javascript, html, import, module, export

I'm learning Javascript and I have a problem using import/export to modularize my code. I tried to learn this by reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) in MDN Web Docs (Mozilla), but failed. **I know this has already been asked here, but I couldn't fix the problem**.

The error I get in the web browser terminal is: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I'll insert a small example of how I tried to use import/export:

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="title">Example</h1>
        <button class="title-button">Change title</button>
        <!--
            I tried adding this line but nothing has changed:
            <script type="module" src="module.js"></script>
        --->
        <script src='main.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**module.js**:

```
const changeTitle = newTitle => {
    const title = document.querySelector(".title");
    
    title.innerHTML = newTitle;
}

export { changeTitle };
```

**main.js**:

```
import { changeTitle } from "./module";

const titleButton = document.querySelector(".title-button");

titleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let newTitle = prompt("Enter new title:");
    
    changeTitle(newTitle);
});
```

**Note**: all three files are in the same folder.

Thank you for your time. Sorry if I made a mistake in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type="module"` attribute **must be added in the script that uses the import statement** (in this case, `main.js`). My mistake was trying to add `type="module"` in `module.js` instead of `main.js`